# forking a process within a django view

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, subprocess

I have a webservice that initiates a process that can take up to a minute. I want to return a 204 that effectively says, "I have successfully gotten your request," but run the slow process in the background.

I am trying to do this by forking another process like this:

```
p = Process(target = modelObj.slowProcess) 
p.start()
logger.debug('sending 204')
return HttpResponse( status=204)
```

This part of the code seems to execute fine, but is tripping up django components. The debug statement is printed, and the process executes, but when I look at the network traffic in chrome's debugger, it says that the upload status is "cancelled". Since I haven't cancelled the event on the browser side, I assume that means the connection died. I never get any response back from the server, so it seems that I'm somehow breaking the request process.

How can I fork that separate process and still have the 204 get delivered?

Comment: `204` means `No content`, and will be interpreted by most user agents in the way you describe. Since you can't display the result of the process immediately anyway, why don't you just send a `200`?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is happening in browser? Can you post an image? It should be working fine.

Comment: I can see you are executing a python function. `modelObj.slowProcess` what's the reason you can't use threads?

Comment: @PauloBu the browser never gets a response. The connection dies.

Comment: @PauloBu it *does* get a response, `204 No Content`, and that will cause it to *close* the connection. That's what's supposed to happen.

Comment: @LukasGraf There is no content to provide, so I used the 204. If I were to give a 200, the only body would be some meaningless "request is being processed" message. I thought 204 to be more appropriate in this instance. (though the status code is not really the problem I'm dealing with(

Comment: There's a difference between getting a response and not getting any. Are you getting 204 No Content or not getting any at all. If the later, try sniffing the network at server side, or print debug statements to see where the server is dying.

Comment: It never gets ANY response. It doesn't get the 204 without content, the connection just dies without any status being returned.

Comment: Well, what would you have expected to happen with a 204? With no content. there's nothing to do for the browser, not even a new page to load (that's why it may look broken to you).

Comment: @LukasGraf with a 204 _there is something to do for the browser_. Acquiring the response (204) and closing the connection. That's different from get hanging.

Comment: @BostonJohn just to discard 204 (which should definitely work). Have you tried sending a dummy response? `return HttpResponse('hello')` for example?

Comment: @BostonJohn how did you determine that the browser never gets a response? Anything else than looking at the output of a decent sniffer is error-prone. Try this: Visit www.google.com first. Then change the URL in the address bar to http://httpbin.org/status/204 and hit enter - is that what you're seeing?

Comment: @PauloBu define "work" - the browser will never load a new page, and the user won't have any feedback that anything happened with a 204 (it will always stay on the page that linked to the URL that's being answered with a 204).

Comment: You guys are 100% right. I am using a hidden iframe to simulate an ajax file upload. but if I return a 204 ot that, the iframe is unhappy

Comment: That's what I mean - returning a `204` is not technically wrong or anything, but it results in a very strange behavior in browsers - that's why I would suggest sending a `200` with a link to where the results of the long running process will be available (or even better `302`), and there do some AJAX polling to display the result of the async process once it's ready. You might also want to take a look at [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/).

Comment: 1) 202 Accepted is better status code for a queued job 2) NEVER fork a process or thread in web viewer, an application container (like uwsgi) never makes a guarantee that a child process will be alive after request is done. 3) Always use Celery (or another job queue) to accomplish long running tasks

Answer (score 1):

The comments showed me what I was doing wrong.

The request in question was from a hidden iframe that was uploading a file. In many instances you can get away with thinking of that as an ajax request, but if the iframe gets back a 204, problems ensue. The iframe has to get back some content event though nothing substantive is being done with that content.